# Assign reference to static variable

Tags: php

I am trying to write a "smart" array search function that would remember the last found item.

```
function &GetShop(&$shops, $id) {
    static $lastShop = null;
    if ($lastShop == null) {
        echo "lastShop is null <br/>";
    } else {
        echo "lastShop: [" . print_r($lastShop, true) . "]<br/>";
    }
    if ($lastShop != null && $lastShop['id'] == $id) {
        return $lastShop;
    }
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($shops); $i++) {
        if ($shops[$i]['id'] == $id) {
            $lastShop = &$shops[$i];
            return $shops[$i];
        }
    }
}

$shops = array(
    array("id"=>"1", "name"=>"bakery"),
    array("id"=>"2", "name"=>"flowers")
);

GetShop($shops, 1);
GetShop($shops, 1);
GetShop($shops, 2);
GetShop($shops, 2);
```

However, there seems to be an issuer with the line:

```
$lastShop = &$shops[$i];
```

When I run this function as it is, I get this output:

```
lastShop is null 
lastShop is null 
lastShop is null 
lastShop is null
```

When I remove the "&" to pass by value instead, it works fine:

```
lastShop is null 
lastShop: [Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => bakery ) ]
lastShop: [Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => bakery ) ]
lastShop: [Array ( [id] => 2 [name] => flowers ) ]
```

I would however like to pass by reference because the found array needs to be modified afterwards. Has somebody encountered this issue before and could advice how he solved it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>You are assigning `NULL` to `$lastShop` at the beginning of the function block on each call. Thus it is always reset to `NULL`.</strike>

I found it in the documentation:

> References are not stored statically: […]
>
> This example demonstrates that when assigning a reference to a static variable, it's not remembered when you call the `&get_instance_ref()` function a second time.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.references

Comment: That does not seem to solve the issue (have tried it), as per the [php documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static) static variables in functions are only initialized on the first call.

Comment: Thanks. Would you have any advice on how I could achieve what I am trying to do (i.e. store the reference to the last found item in the array)?