# How to work keyword static

Tags: php

I made some test, and what i get...look at this:

**First:**

```
function a()
{
    static $number = 0;
    echo "[".$number."]";
    $number++;
    echo "-[".$number."]\n";
}
a();
a();
a();
```

*Result:*

`[0]-[1]
 [1]-[2]
 [2]-[3]`

**Second:**

```
$digit = 10;
function a()
{
    static $number = 0;
    echo "[".$number."]";
    $number = &$GLOBALS["digit"];
    $number++;
    echo "-[".$number."]\n";
}
a();
a();
a();
```

*Result:*

`[0]-[11]
 [0]-[12]
 [0]-[13]`

**Third:**

```
$digit = 10;
function a()
{
    static $number = 0;
    $number++;
    echo "[".$number."]";
    $number = &$GLOBALS["digit"];
    echo "-[".$number."]\n";
}
a();
a();
a();
```

*Result:*

`[1]-[10]
[2]-[10]
[3]-[10]`

**Fourth:**

```
$digit = 10;
function a()
{
    static $number = 0;
    $number++;
    echo "[".$number."]";
    unset($number);
    $number = &$GLOBALS["digit"];
    echo "-[".$number."]\n";
}
a();
a();
a();
```

*Result:*

`[1]-[10]
[2]-[10]
[3]-[10]`

Explain me please why this so work? I dont understand why when we call next function static variable is reset (Second example). Why in third example static variable is not reset but when we call function again i dont get value from $GLOBALS (besides i dont see difference between third example and fourth example). Explain anyone.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12991013/669576

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is really just a lack of understanding [PHP variable scope](http://php.net/language.variables.scope) which covers [static function variables](http://php.net/language.variables.scope#language.variables.scope.static), and [references in PHP](http://php.net/language.references).

## First

In your first example, this is all normal and expected behavior. Static function variables are **initialized once at compile time**. Any changes to their value inside the function remains until the script ends. So they aren't re-initialized after the function returns, like normal *local variables* would be.

## Second

In your second example, you are only changing the value of the global `$digit` variable, because you re-assign the local variable `$number` by reference to the global variable `$digit`. So it's the same thing as saying `global $digit; $number = &$digit;` in your function. It imports the global variable into the function's local scope.

Note, this doesn't reset the statically initialized value. The value was always `0` and never changed. Notice what the example below would do.

```
$digit = 10;
function a()
{
    static $number = 0;
    echo "[".$number."]";
    $number++;
    // this by reference assignment doesn't change the static $number value PHP remembers
    $number = &$GLOBALS["digit"];
    $number++;
    echo "-[".$number."]\n";
}
a();
a();
a();
```

```
[0]-[11]
[1]-[12]
[2]-[13]
```

## Third

You're doing the same thing by importing the global variable, but you just so happen to increment the value of the local variable `$number`, first, before you reassign it as a reference to `$digits` from the global scope.

## Fourth

Same thing as three. `unset($number)` has no effect here. PHP doesn't forget the value of the static variable `$number` just because you delete it from the function's local scope. The statically initialized value remains in PHP's memory until the script ends. So technically, you can re-assign the local variable by reference, like you did in examples two and three, and the value of `$number` that was initialized at compile time still remains.

Comment: if i right your understand, so in third example `static $number;` and `number = &$GLOBALS["digit"];` different variables?

Comment: No, obviously the variable name is the same. However, they happen to reference different values at different times throughout the function. When the function is first called, the variable references the static value that was first initialized by the compiler (from your `static` declaration). After you assign it by reference to the global variable `$digit`, it then references the value of the global variable `$digit`. The variable just points to some value. The variable itself isn't the value.

Comment: I dont understand then... If we assign a static variable reference to another variable that is why the link is not retained the next time the function is called?

Comment: The link is retained. You just changed it when you did `$number = &$GLOBALS["digit"]`.

Comment: `$digit = 10;
function a()
{
    static $number;
    echo "[".$number."]";
    if(!isset($number))
    {
     $number = &$GLOBALS["digit"];
     echo "Linked";
    }
    $number++;
    echo "-[".$number."]\n";
}
a();
a();
a();`

result:

`[]Linked-[11]
[]Linked-[12]
[]Linked-[13]`

Comment: i dont understand

Comment: What don't you understand, exactly? `$number` is `null` there. [`isset()`](http://php.net/isset) returns `false` for any variable that is `null`. `echo null` gives you empty string. Pretty self-explanatory code.

Comment: i know how to work isset but i dont understand how to work static variable, can u make chat and we can continue our discussion there?

Comment: Read the documentation I pointed you to in the answer. It's all explained there at length. I'm afraid this now far exceeds the scope of your question. Stack Overflow is not a place to get one-on-one personal assistance and hand-holding. We are all busy. Please do your due diligence, research, read documentation carefully, and just keep playing around with the code like you're doing. Eventually you will get there. I see no point in further discussion here. The question has been thoroughly answered.

Comment: I see that you have carefully tried when you wrote me an answer, I have read the documentation and there is little written. It says that the static variable does not store references, and why is not clear, so I tried to find out why she does not retain what is the reason?

Comment: You keep going back to the value isn't retained, but I've repeatedly explained that it is. ***You just keep changing that value in your code by assigning to the global variable***. I'm not sure how else to say that. ***You are the one that changed the value***. You and you alone did this. It has nothing to do with static variables. ***Not a thing***.

Comment: This is clearly explained and even demonstrated in my answer by showing you that increminting `$number` ***before*** you assign by reference to `$GLOBALS["digit"]` ***does in fact change the value of the static variable and that that value is retained after calling the function again***. **You** assigned `$number` by reference to `$GLOBALS["digit"]`. **You** changed the value of `$number` by doing so. **You** get the same result with any other variable that wasn't static. There is ***absolutely nothing strange about any of this***. You just seem to be confusing yourself.

Comment: ***None of this behavior is any way, shape, form, manner, facsimile, or denomination, specific to `static` variables. This is just how variables work in PHP***. So read the ***entire*** language reference on variables provided in the answer, and not just briefly skim over the examples in the code. There is a lot of information there that you need to digest, with plenty of links referencing additional material.

Comment: Does this thoroughly satisfy your lack of understanding?

Comment: Because you're over-thinking it. There's absolutely nothing difficult to understand here. You are just writing contrived nonsensical, meaningless code right now. Spend less time trying to do that and more time trying to solve a real problem and eventually all this stuff will make more sense. There's no point in trying to solve contrived problems. That is why they are called contrived.

Comment: I read all your links more than once ... I probably stupid ... X_X

Comment: You're not stupid. You're just trying to understand something that you aren't familiar with or knowledgeable about. Without either of those things you have very little prospect of understanding. The more time you spend writing code the more familiar you become with different coding principles/concepts. The more documentation you read the more knowledgeable you become. The two go hand-in-hand, but ultimately this requires a lot of time going back and forth between filling your knowledge coffer and getting more acquainted with new language syntax and constructs.